# Bash function and for loop

Tags: bash

I created a function and every time I execute the script it spawns thousands of processes until the box crashes. I am not sure what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
ping () {
    for i in {1..254};
    do
        (ping -c1 -W1 10.0.0.$i)
    done
while true;
do
    read -rep $'What method do you want to use' method
    if [ $method == "ping" ];
    then
        ping
    else
        echo "Wrong method"
done
```

Comment: BTW -- `if [ $method == "ping" ]` should be `if [ "$method" = ping ]`. Expansions need to be quoted to prevent string-splitting and globbing; constant strings with values known not to contain literal spaces, glob characters, &c. don't. And `==` isn't a valid operator in `test` -- bash offers it as an extension, which is why your code is working when you test it, but POSIX only specifies `=`.

Comment: ...consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking about it here.

Comment: @SachinMokashi, re: your edit -- multi-line code blocks should be formatted with four-space indents, not backticks. See the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: ...btw, the parens in `(ping ...)` contributed to the problem by running code in a subprocess, causing a fork -- otherwise this would have only had one process looping but not crashed the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is recursing.

Use `command ping` to use the real ping command, rather than your function -- or, better, name it something other than `ping`.

That is:

```
# bad: shadows "ping" with a command that does something different
# ...but at least it doesn't recurse
ping() {
  for ((i=1; i<=254; i++)); do
    command ping -c1 -W1 "10.0.0.$i"
  done
}
```

Or, better:

```
# good: name doesn't shadow the traditional ping command
pingAll() {
  for ((i=1; i<=254; i++)); do
    ping -c1 -W1 "10.0.0.$i"
  done
}
```

Comment: Wow I have been staring way to hard at it and totally missed it. Fixed it, Thanks!